# Docker rootless failed to create shim task

Tags: docker, runtime, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

- server: debian-11
- docker: 23.0.1

I followed instructions from https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

after running the deamon `dockerd-rootless.sh` I got

```
open /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1004.slice/cgroup.controllers: no such file or directory
```

I manualy created the directory with chown on my user (certidock) then I get the following error:

```bash
certidock@cont-test:/etc/profile.d$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply cgroup configuration: unable to start unit "docker-7d0ec8e9f2be784420ada3f5b4a3a7ce89cc0c2bcc1cfe92cda1950b7c9461d4.scope" (properties [{Name:Description Value:"libcontainer container 7d0ec8e9f2be784420ada3f5b4a3a7ce89cc0c2bcc1cfe92cda1950b7c9461d4"} {Name:Slice Value:"user.slice"} {Name:Delegate Value:true} {Name:PIDs Value:@au [59175]} {Name:MemoryAccounting Value:true} {Name:CPUAccounting Value:true} {Name:IOAccounting Value:true} {Name:TasksAccounting Value:true} {Name:DefaultDependencies Value:false}]): Permission denied: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

Comment: No but I went for Podman which works fine with rootless containers! https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md. The syntax is all the same and even more simple without Deamon to execute tasks.
But podman currently doesn't work on a debian11. On Ubuntu 22 OK!